# What's the best solution (audio quality) to giving online music classes

Tags: software, teaching

Because of COVID-19, I'm giving piano classes via Internet to my students. Problem is:

When my student plays soft passages (in *piano* or *pianissimo*), audio either rises in volume or is clipped entirely. And overall the audio compression blocks me from analysing dynamics in my student's playing.

I need a solution (desktop/mobile app/web based/whatever) which **doesn't compress the audio**, either mine or from my student. It seems all solutions I've tested (below) are optimized only for speech (which is compreensible). I've used to this moment:

- Google Meet (or Hangouts Meet)
- Jitsi Meet
- Zoom

Any ideas?

**Edit (May 28, 2021):** As this question was considered off-topic, I want to clarify that I'm not "seeking recommendations for specific equipment", but trying to solve a common problem with music classes in a pandemic scenario. The "required function and setting in which the equipment will be used" is, as clearly stated in the original question, a video conferencing solution that **doesn't compress the audio**, just that.

As I searched through past year, the simplest solution is a configuration in Zoom, as [@Deb's answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/96590/48077). Another (non-free and not-so-simple) option is [Audiomovers Listento](https://audiomovers.com/wp/), that a faculty professor is using in one of my doctorate disciplines. I didn't test it anyway.

Comment: Don't feel bad for the closing as off-topic, it's still a relevant question and Zoom is still the right answer.

Comment: This is still off topic here - your question is a general online broadcast / conferencing one.

Comment: I edited the title adding the word "music", to make more explicitly obvious that is an issue only faced by musicians, not a "general online broadcast / conferencing one" (although, being it in a music forum, from the start it's pretty obviously related to music classes. But it seems I didn't make it clear enough.)

Comment: But, if you wish, I can ask also for some notes or chords, as it seems only these are seem as musical subjects. As if musician's specific everyday's problems in a pandemic scenario (still very present in many countries) were less musical-related than a diminished chord.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using enabling Zoom's "preserve original sound"? I thought this was exactly what it's supposed to be for.

Comment: Also, ask them to uncheck the box which automatically changes the microphone volume in Zoom.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking at something like [VST Connect](https://www.steinberg.net/en/products/vst/vst_connect/vst_connect_performer.html) which comes in Pro & Performer flavours & several platforms, Mac/PC/iOS.
I've never used it myself but I was around at Steinberg when the betas were first being tested & reports were good.

Comment: "which comes in Pro & Performer flavours" of *Steinberg Cubase*, do you mean? Thank you, @Tetsujin. Your solution is a little overhead for me, as I use Reaper in Linux as my DAW, and my student doesn't use any DAW at all, and isn't appealed to technology in general. But thanks anyway!